# QML: design view when using multiple .qrc files

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

When I split QML files into different `.qrc` files (but within the same project), QtCreator's design mode as well as general IDE support for these files) will no longer work (i.e. if a QML file from `a.qrc` imports a file that is in `b.qrc`, all IDE level symbol resolution fails to work).

Resolution works fine at runtime (the different resource files are linked using `RESOURCES += a.qrc b.qrc`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to import your local QML definitions, for example:

```
import "../preferences"
```

Alternatively you can also place a bunch of these lines somewhere in the project (and call that from your main function)

```
qmlRegisterType(QUrl("qrc:/a/NiceButton.qml"), "my.namespace", 1, 0, "NiceButton");
```

(Assuming you put the stuff in `a.qrc` in the folder `a`). You can put the following on top of QML's in `b.qrc`

```
import my.namespace 1.0
```

However, the more complicated and probably better way would be to write plugins that allow you to put `import my.plugin.namespace 1.0` on top of you QML files; for which Qt wrote a tutorial themselves: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html